# Separate integer and other numeric columns in MATLAB table

Tags: matlab, matlab-table

I have a table (csv) stored using datastore function and I'd like to separate the integer columns (categorical) in a table and the float columns (numerical) in another table. I tried the following code

```
int_col = all(round(Data) == Data,1);
cat_data = Data(:,int_cols);
num_data = Data(:,~int_cols);
```

but I get the following error

> Undefined function round for input of type table

Comment: btw, there's a categorical type you can use: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/categorical.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to first convert the table to an array (using `table2array`) before performing your check for integer values.

```
t = table(rand(5,1), randi(5,5,1), 'VariableNames', {'floats', 'ints'});

%// Look for integer columns
isInt = ~any(mod(table2array(t), 1));

%// Grab the columns that are integers
integer_table = t(:,isInt);

%// Grab the non-integer columns
non_integer_table = t(:,~isInt);
```